# How to give a description to an alias defined in mix.exs?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

When I define an alias in the `mix.exs` and run `mix help`, it just shows its description as "Alias defined in mix.exs".

Suppose, for example, I have this `mix.exs`:

```
  defp aliases do
    [
      play: "run --no-halt"
    ]
  end
```

Then, the `mix help` command displays task list like this:

```
...
mix local.rebar       # Installs Rebar locally
mix new               # Creates a new Elixir project
mix play              # Alias defined in mix.exs
mix profile.cprof     # Profiles the given file or expression with cprof
mix profile.eprof     # Profiles the given file or expression with eprof
...
```

How can I give a description to the `play` task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output from `mix help` comes from the `@shortdoc` [attribute](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#module-attributes) in a custom mix task

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Play do
  use Mix.Task
  @shortdoc "run with --no-halt"

  @impl Mix.Task
  def run(_) do
    Mix.Task.run("run", ["--no-halt"])
  end
end
```

```sh
mix help | grep "mix play"
mix play                  # run with --no-halt
```

I don't think there is a way to add help docs for aliases.